# Why isn't a new created file local?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, local, createfile

I have the problem, that I create a new file in a Java program, but I always get an exception, that the new created file is not local, when I try to open it on the eclipse project explorer view. 
The code where I create it is as follows:

```
IWorkspaceRoot workspaceRoot = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
IProject project = workspaceRoot.getProject(projectName);

FileUtil myFile = new FileUtil();

if (!project.getFile(FILE_NAME).exists()) {

    IFile newFile = project.getFile("conf.txt");
    FileInputStream fileStream = null;
    try {
        String temp = project + "/conf.txt";
        temp = temp.substring(2);
        fileStream = new FileInputStream(temp);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
      try {
        newFile.create(fileStream, false, null);
    } catch (CoreException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
      // create closes the file stream, so no worries. 

    try {
        myFile.writeTextFile(FILE_NAME, "Seconds", output);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`FileUtil` is a class which only implements the methods write and read for the file.

The `Exception` I get when I try to open it begins with:

```
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource '/ProjectE1/conf.txt' is not local.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkLocal(Resource.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContentDescription(File.java:264)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.propertytester.FilePropertyTester.testContentType(FilePropertyTester.java:108)
```

I somehow have to get a relative path during the runtime. Because I am opening a new instance of eclipse in the program, where I can see the Project in the Project Explorer but can't open the conf.txt file because it is not local.

Comment: `/ProjectE1/conf.txt` is an absolute reference (ie, it's searching for the file starting from the root of the current drive/device).  It's likely that the path does not exist

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your resource is an absolute path to /ProjectE1/conf.txt, I'm confused why you are not using java.io.

This will help you understand relative paths, I think this may be where you are wanting to put your conf file.

```
File file = new File("conf.txt");
if(!file.createNewFile()){
    //err
}
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: How do I get a relative path? I thought java.io creates files, which are not physically on the hard drive. I want to the file to be permanent in my eclipse-runtime folder.

Comment: To get a relative path just remove the first frontslash of the path.  ie conf.txt is a relative path.  java.io can create files wherever you want, you just have to decide where you want to keep the file. @Annika

Comment: Thanks, but I don´t know how to use java.io with the class IWorkspace because I don´t know otherwise how to get the workspace root to the project. Do you know how to get the Workspace root using the classes in java.io?

Comment: edited my answer, that may help you.  If you are not modifying eclipse workspaces/projects in your code using the ResourcePlugin class is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue.  This is how I fixed.

1. First created file in local file system (using java.io)
2. Did project refresh
3. Reload the file

   ```
           File file = new File(project.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation() + project.getFullPath().toString() + "/relative_path_of_my_file");
           file.createNewFile();
           project.refreshLocal(IProject.DEPTH_INFINITE, null);
           keywordFile = project.getFile("/relative_path_of_my_file");
   ```